# When I pass a variable in an hidden input field the value gets splitted

Tags: jquery

The variable `sub_product_title` value is `"Hettich InnoTech Plain Drawer"` however when setting it as hidden element value I am getting it as `<input type="hidden" drawer="" plain="" innotech="" value="Hettich" name="item-0"/>`

Comment: And the question is....??

Comment: This is how i am getting value :<input type="hidden" name="item-0" drawer="" plain="" innotech="" value="Hettich">

Comment: please explain what do you want ... and what is working and what is not .. and its better to provide html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the text within quotes. i.e. `value="' + sub_product_title + '"`

```
$('.sub-product_add').click(function(e) {
    var sub_product_title = $(this).parents('.span6.mb10').children('.span7').children('.sub_product_title').html();
    $('#added-cabinets-Base').children('tbody:last').append('<tr><td><span><input type="hidden" value="' + sub_product_title + '" name="item-0"/><a href="#" class="img-hover">' + sub_product_title + '</a><img id="hover-img" src=' + sub_product_img + '></span></td><td><i cla**strong text**ss="fa fa-inr"></i><span class="cal-price">' + sub_product_price + '</span></td><td><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></td></tr>');                                 
});
```